# Findind index of words in a list of words

Tags: python, list, nlp, python-re

For BIO tagging problem, I'm looking for a way to find the index of specific words in a list of strings.

For example:

```
text = "Britain has reduced its carbon emissions more than any rich country"
word = 'rich'
print(text.split())
['Britain', 'has', 'reduced', 'its', 'carbon', 'emissions', 'more', 'than', 'any', 'rich', 'country']

text.split(' ').index(word) # returns 9

text.split(' ').index('rich country') # occurring an error as expected
```

My desired answer would be:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I think I can just use a loop to find the first word's index and the last word's index and then replace them into either in 0 or 1.

However my question is what if the `text` list would be like this:

```
['Britain', 'has', 'reduced', 'its', 'carbon', 'emissions', 'more', 'than', 'any', 'rich', 'count', '_ry']
```

or maybe

```
['Britain', 'has', 'reduced', 'its', 'carbon', 'emissions', 'more', 'than', 'any', 'richcountry']
```

I believe I can solve this problem with using dirty for loops, but I believe there would be another clean and simple way to solve this task.

I would appreciate if you guys could give me any advice on this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer of your first question:

```
text = "Britain has reduced its carbon emissions more than any rich country"
words = 'rich country'.split(" ")
split_text = text.split()
[1 if x in words else 0 for x in split_text]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

The second issue will require fuzzy matching, which can be achieved with [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
words = 'rich country'.split(" ")
split_text = ['Britain', 'has', 'reduced', 'its', 'carbon', 'emissions', 'more', 'than', 'any', 'richcountry']
[1 if process.extractBests(x, words, score_cutoff = 60) else 0 for x in split_text]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

And for

```
split_text = ['Britain', 'has', 'reduced', 'its', 'carbon', 'emissions', 'more', 'than', 'any', 'rich', 'count', '_ry']
[1 if process.extractBests(x, words, score_cutoff = 60) else 0 for x in split_text]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Note that you can set a threshold value with `score_cutoff`.